# How to optimise the $filter in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

Is there a way to configure/work with the angular $filter so that you can pass data to it gradually an not have it always iterate over the whole data but just the previous data filtered ?

I am currently trying to split the a user provided string to run multiple sequential filers on the data. So if I have a data like so: [{name:foo, city:bar},...x250] I could type in the search box "Paris" from that point I should be iteration only on the place in Paris and then type Hotel and then Hilton.... The problem is the filter runs each and every time on the whole data set... Does anyone know how to run the filter sequentially in angular ?

updates...

http://jsfiddle.net/Bretto/ZM4Qa/12/

```
.filter('searchFilter', function ($filter) {

return function (array, q) {

    console.log('data-entry: ', array.length);

    var filter = $filter('filter');

    var lookFor = function (word, data, cb) {
        var dataRes = filter(data, word);
        cb(dataRes);
    }


    var search = function (index, words, data, cb) {
        var word = words[index];
        lookFor(word, data, function (dataRes) {
            console.log('data-current: ', dataRes.length);
            if (index < words.length - 1) {
                index += 1;
                search(index, words, dataRes, cb);
            } else {
                cb(dataRes);
            }
        });
    }

    if (q && q.text) {
        var words = q.text.split(' ');
        var index = 0;

        if(array){
            //console.log(array.length);
        }

        search(index, words, array, function (dataRes) {
            array = dataRes;
        });
    }
    return array;
}
```

})

So this is an attempt to create a filter that gradually iterates over the previous filtered results (type multiple words separated by a space in the input...) the issue is that the filter always starts from the whole data.

is this clearer now ?

Comment: Can you create a plunker to demonstrate the problem clearer ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use multiple filters, so you don't have to go tweaking everything
Take this example as a starting point

http://jsfiddle.net/ed9A2/1/

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in playersFound = (players | filter:{id: player_id, name:player_name, age:player_age})">
```